# Prestashop helper form 'file' type

Tags: forms, file-upload, prestashop, helper

I m working on prestasshop and I created a helper form inside a controller (for back office). My question is how to upload a document by using the type:'file' from the helper form. Here is the code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->context = Context::getContext();
    $this->table = 'games';
    $this->className = 'Games';
    $this->lang = true;
    $this->addRowAction('edit');
    $this->addRowAction('delete');
    $this->bulk_actions = array('delete' => array('text' => $this->l('Delete selected'),
    'confirm' => $this->l('Delete selected items?')));
    $this->multishop_context = Shop::CONTEXT_ALL;

    $this->fieldImageSettings = array(
        'name' => 'image',
        'dir' => 'games'
    );

    $this->fields_list = array(
        'id_game' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('ID'),
            'width' => 25
        )
    );

    $this->identifier = 'id_game';
    parent::__construct();
}

public function renderForm()
{
    if (!($obj = $this->loadObject(true)))
        return;

    $games_list = Activity::getGamesList();     

    $this->fields_form = array(
        'tinymce' => true,          
        'legend' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Game'),
            'image' => '../img/admin/tab-payment.gif'
        ),
        'input' => array(
            array(
                  'type' => 'select',
                  'label' => $this->l('Game:'),
                  'desc' => $this->l('Choose a Game'),
                  'name' => 'id_games',
                  'required' => true,
                  'options' => array(
                        'query' => $games_list,
                        'id' => 'id_game',
                        'name' => 'name'
                    )
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => $this->l('Game Title:'),
                'name' => 'name',
                'size' => 64,
                'required' => true,
                'lang' => true,
                'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' <>;=#{}'
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'file',
                'label' => $this->l('Photo:'),
                'name' => 'uploadedfile',
                'id' => 'uploadedfile',
                'display_image' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'desc' => $this->l('Upload your document')
            )
        )
    );

    $this->fields_form['submit'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('   Save   '),
        'class' => 'button'
    );

    return AdminController::renderForm();
}
```

Now how can I upload the document?
Do I have to create a column in the table of the db (games table) for storing the file or something related?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this AdminController for your model. Now a model obviously can't hold a file in table column. What you can do is hold path to the uploaded file. That's what you can save.

You should look in AdminController class (which you extended). When you submit a form, one of two method are executed:

```
processAdd()
processUpdate()
```

Now investigate the flow logic in these methods. Other methods are called from within this methods, such as:

```
$this->beforeAdd($this->object); -> calls $this->_childValidation();
$this->validateRules();
$this->afterUpdate($object);
```

As you can see, there these are the methods where you can do you custom stuff. If you look up these functions in AdminController class, the're empty. They are purposely added so people can override them and put their custom logic there.

So, using these functions, you can validate your uploaded file fields (even though it isnt in the model itself), if it validates you can then assign path to the object; and then in beforeAdd method you can actually move the uploaded file to the desired location (because both child validation and default validation has passed).

The way I've done it:

```
protected function _childValidation()
{
   // Check upload errors, file type, writing permissions
   // Use $this->errors['file'] if there is an error;

protected function beforeAdd($object)
{
   // create filename and filepath
   // assign these fields to object;

protected function afterAdd($object)
{
   // move the file
```

If you allow the file field to be updated, you'll need to to these steps for Update methods as well.

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply! In this case where should I write the actual code for the actual uploading? Something like ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)).

Answer (score 1):

you can get uploaded file using $_FILES['uploadedfile'] in both the functions processAdd() and processUpdate(), you can check all the conditions there and before calling $this->object->save(); to save the form data you can write the code to upload the file in the desired location like

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)

since you can't save the file in database you need to save only the name of the file or location on the database

Hope that helps